# Reset value of custom sum field when using actions\Copy Order

Tags: acumatica

I've got a couple custom summary fields that I'm using to calculate totals. It seems like the lines are totaling them correctly, but given that Acumatica is not recalculating the SUM each time, but rather altering it, when I copy I end up with a total that's double.

I tried this code (which is hijacked from a different post of someone having almost exactly the same issue) but I don't think it's even running. I'm guessing I have a big gap in my understanding of what should be happening here.

```
      public delegate void CopyOrderProcDel(SOOrder order, CopyParamFilter copyFilter);

    [PXOverride]
    public void CopyOrderProc(SOOrder order, CopyParamFilter copyFilter, CopyOrderProcDel del)
    {

Base.RowSelecting.AddHandler<SOOrder>((sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Row == null) return;

            SOOrderExt orderExt = sender.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>(e.Row);
            orderExt.UsrSpeedyTotalCost = 0m;
            orderExt.UsrSpeedyTotalExt2 = 0m;

        });
        del(order, copyFilter);
```

For what it's worth, I've created a menu with an action button that does fix the summary fields, but that's a very clunky solution for the users.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at overriding RowUpdating/ed via adding the handler in CopyOrderPRoc. Set the values to zero and then when the lines are later inserted should calc your values. Also there is a property you can use if needed "IsCopyOrder" to know if the process is doing the copy process or not.

Comment: I guess I'm confused, because I thought that's exactly what I was doing with that code, and yet it seems to do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to reset your custom fields. Do it this way.

```
public delegate void CopyOrderProcDelegate(SOOrder sourceOrder, CopyParamFilter copyFilter);
[PXOverride]
public void CopyOrderProc(SOOrder sourceOrder, CopyParamFilter copyFilter, CopyOrderProcDelegate baseMethod)
{
  baseMethod(sourceOrder,copyFilter);
  SOOrderExt orderExt = Base.Document.Current.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>();
  orderExt.UsrSpeedyTotalCost = 0m;
  orderExt.UsrSpeedyTotalExt2 = 0m;

}
```